# How to fix this Flutter error: The superclass 'Bloc<NumberTriviaEvent, NumberTriviaState>' doesn't have a zero argument constructor

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I'm following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dc3B_mMrZ-Q&t=11033s&ab_channel=ResoCoder

Unfortunately I have the latest version of FLutter and also installed th elatest versions of all th e dependencies, so the code has to change for some breaking changes.

I get this error:

The superclass 'Bloc<NumberTriviaEvent, NumberTriviaState>' doesn't have a zero argument constructor.
Try declaring a zero argument constructor in 'Bloc<NumberTriviaEvent, NumberTriviaState>', or explicitly invoking a different constructor in 'Bloc<NumberTriviaEvent, NumberTriviaState>'.

This is the relevant part of the code:

```
class NumberTriviaBloc extends Bloc<NumberTriviaEvent, NumberTriviaState> {
  final GetConcreteNumberTrivia getConcreteNumberTrivia;
  final GetRandomNumberTrivia getRandomNumberTrivia;
  final InputConverter inputConverter;

  NumberTriviaBloc({
    @required GetConcreteNumberTrivia concrete,
    @required GetRandomNumberTrivia random,
    @required this.inputConverter,
  })  : assert(concrete != null),
        assert(random != null),
        assert(inputConverter != null),
        getConcreteNumberTrivia = concrete,
        getRandomNumberTrivia = random;

  NumberTriviaState get initialState => Empty();

  @override
  Stream<NumberTriviaState> mapEventToState(
    NumberTriviaEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is GetTriviaForConcreteNumber) {
      final inputEither =
          inputConverter.stringToUnsignedInteger(event.numberString);
      yield* inputEither.fold(
        (failure) async* {
          yield Error(message: INVALID_INPUT_FAILURE_MESSAGE);
        },
        (integer) async* {
          yield Loading();
          final failureOrTrivia =
              await getConcreteNumberTrivia(Params(number: integer));
          yield* _eitherLoadedOrerrorState(failureOrTrivia);
        },
      );
    } else if (event is GetTriviaForRandomNumber) {
      yield Loading();
      final failureOrTrivia = await getRandomNumberTrivia(NoParams());
      yield* _eitherLoadedOrerrorState(failureOrTrivia);
    }
  }

  Stream<NumberTriviaState> _eitherLoadedOrerrorState(
    Either<Failure, NumberTrivia> failureOrTrivia,
  ) async* {
    yield failureOrTrivia.fold(
      (failure) => Error(message: _mapFailureToMessage(failure)),
      (trivia) => Loaded(trivia: trivia),
    );
  }

  String _mapFailureToMessage(Failure failure) {
    switch (failure.runtimeType) {
      case ServerFailure:
        return SERVER_FAILURE_MESSAGE;
      case CacheFailure:
        return CACHE_FAILURE_MESSAGE;
      default:
        return 'Unexpected error';
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried adding a call to super in like this:

```
  NumberTriviaBloc({
    @required GetConcreteNumberTrivia concrete,
    @required GetRandomNumberTrivia random,
    @required this.inputConverter,
  })  : assert(concrete != null),
        assert(random != null),
        assert(inputConverter != null),
        getConcreteNumberTrivia = concrete,
        getRandomNumberTrivia = random,
        super(Empty());
```

This fixes the compilation error but I don't know what I should pass in to the super call.

I'm very new to Flutter and Dart (as in this is the first time I've looked at them in any depth).

Thanks for any insight you can give me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what flutter bloc you used.
There is a change at setting initial state from v5.0.0.
https://bloclibrary.dev/#/migration?id=%E2%9D%97initialstate-has-been-removed

So you need to pass initial state at super constructor.

Comment: Thanks, it's flutter_bloc 7.0.0 so this change was the breaking change. See my replies to Corxx5f above.

Answer (score 0):

> TLDR you should pass the initialState of your bloc.

See the official docs the problem is that the `initialState` is now passed to the super instead of being an attribute you have to override.

See this example of their [docs](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) as the state is of type `int` the initial state is 0 and is passed to the superclass.

```
class CounterCubit extends Cubit<int> {
  CounterCubit() : super(0);

  void increment() => emit(state + 1);
  void decrement() => emit(state - 1);
}
```

Also you could use `Cubit` for more simple use cases instead of a full bloc.

Comment: Thanks, so by passing in Empty() to the super that is the correct way to do this (since Empty() is the initial state?

Comment: Oh, and this line: NumberTriviaState get initialState => Empty(); is no longer necessary?

Comment: Yes FrankCazabon you are correct and @KuKu pointed the exact version at which the bloc library introduced the breaking change

Answer (score 0):

Hey I've been having the same problem following this tutorial the answer is pretty simple.
All you have to do is to pass InitialNumberTriviaState() to the super constructor of bloc -

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import './bloc.dart';

class NumberTriviaBloc extends Bloc<NumberTriviaEvent, NumberTriviaState> {
  NumberTriviaBloc() : super(InitialNumberTriviaState());

  @override
  Stream<NumberTriviaState> mapEventToState(
    NumberTriviaEvent event,
  ) async* {
    // TODO: Add Logic
  }
}
```